# Format send email subject and body in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on changing `Send-MailMessage` formatting based on error or success. When there is an error, I would like to have the `Subject` and email `Body` text appear in red color. On success, I would like to change the `Subject` and email body text to Blue color. I was able to change the success email body to Blue color but the Subject and error email body does not work as expected.

[image: error]

***PoSh Code:***

```
$Emailsubject = "<p style=""color:red;"">Error occured</p><br><br>"
$ErrorMessage = "<p style=""color:red;"">" New-Object System.Exception ("Error: " + $error[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString())"</p><br><br>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new object if you're just interested in interpolating the Inner Exception [`Message`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.message?view=net-6.0) you can simply use the [Subexpression operator `$( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-).

For example:

```bash
try {
    throw [System.Exception]::new('', 'some inner exception')
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = "<p style=""color:red;"">Error: $($error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message)</p><br><br>"
}
```

`$ErrorMessage` would become the following in HTML:

```html
<p style="color:red;">Error: some inner exception</p><br><br>
```

As aside, using the [`.ToString()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-exception-tostring) is definitely not recommended in this case, if the error you're catching **does not have an Inner Exception**, you would get a new error.

For Example:

```bash
try {
    throw [System.Exception]::new('does not have inner exception')
}
catch {
    $ErrorMessage = "<p style=""color:red;"">Error: $($error[0].Exception.InnerException.ToString())</p><br><br>"
}
```

Would result in the following Error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.